# php -i executed from command line and phpinfo executed from browser show different php parameters

Tags: apache-2.2, php, command-line-interface, zend-framework

My problem is that when I execute `php -i` it shows the php version as php 5.4 and the loaded config file as `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`. When I execute the script `phpinfo.php` from the command line it shows php 5.3 and the loaded config file as `/etc/php.ini`.

How can I enable the default PHP interpreter as php 5.3?

I need 5.3 because php 5.3 is configured with PDO and `pdo_mysql` where php 5.4 is not configured with it also the zend version of php 5.3 is 220090626 whereas that of php 5.4 is 220090525.

When I try to execute a PHP script from a browser it is being compiled with php 5.4 (which doesn't have the PDO extension) and is throwing a fatal error as undefined PDO.

How do I configure my Apache to load php 5.3 for the scripts.

The `phpinfo.php` script is as follows

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your php.ini is in /usr/local/lib?  That's so completely wrong, no package manager would put that file there.

You must have a locally built copy of php on your host.  `which php` will show you where it is. `which -a php` will show you all of the installed versions of php that are in your $PATH.
Run `php -v` on each one to see which version it is.

Remove the versions you don't want, and you'll have php 5.3 left. If you can't remove them, then change your $PATH so the one you want comes first, e.g. `PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` if you want /usr/bin/php instead of /usr/local/bin/php.  Or, define a shell alias:

```
alias php=/usr/bin/php
```

and put it into your shell startup files (~/.bashrc or ~/.profile) so that that version always gets run when you type just `php`.

Comment: insteading of removing them can i just disable them from running. if yes , how ??    which -a php showed these output         /usr/local/bin/php
/usr/bin/php
/usr/local/bin/php      how would i know which of them is php 5.3 ??

Comment: sorry i didnt mentioned before ,  it is a Virtual Private Server (VPS)

Comment: Edited to describe that.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Andrew Schulman  ........ Editing the $PATH worked for me.  One more thing, can we  write that shell alias in a php script instead of a shell .

Comment: No, because you're running the `php` command from the shell.  You can put it into your shell startup files so it's always available, though - edited to describe that.